# How to formulate argmax

Tags: probability

## Problem

Let $x$ be a data point and $P(c_k|x) \in [0,1]$ the probability that $x$ belongs to class $c_k$ where $k=1...n$. A data point $x$ can thus belong to one of the $c_k$ classes. I want to select the class $c_k$ with the highest probability

---

## Example

$x \rightarrow \{P(c_1|x), P(c_2|x),..., P(c_n|x)\} $. Suppose $P(c_1|x)$ has the highest probability which is equal to $1$. then $x = c_1$.

How can I use $argmax$ in order to formulate this statement?

---

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an $x$, if you want to notate "the class which $x$ has the highest probability of belonging to", you could write:

$$
\underset{k}{\text{argmax}}~P(c_k | x)
$$

That would return a class.

Comment: well thank you @Eli Rose. I compared it to what I formulated earlier. sounds correct.